# How create the infinite route with one component in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I lately get a project with Nuxt.js and facing some problems with it.
I have a component that gets some products from an API and gets them from Vuex.
Each product may have an array of children and each child may have an array of children and so on.

```js
import Images from '@/components/products/Images'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    Images
  },
  data () {
    return {
      images: [],
      options: {
        width: 300,
        padding: {
          2: 8,
          default: 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      products: 'getProducts'
    })
  },
  mounted () {
    this.images = this.products.filter(
      item => item.slug === this.$route.params.slug
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container_pic">
    <div class="flow-root">
      <div
        v-for="(item, index) in images"
        :key="index"
        class="w-full md:p-4 py-4"
      >
        <h6 class="text-lg mt-6 mb-8">
          {{ item.title }}
        </h6>
        <Images
          :item="item"
          :slug="true"
          :childs="item.childs"
          large
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Products data can be like this:

```js
products: {
  { id: 1, childs: [], title: "title 1" },
  { id: 2, childs: [
    { id: 3, childs: [], title: "title 3" },
    { id: 4, childs: [
      { id: 5, childs: [
        { id: 6, childs: [], title: "title 6" },
      ], title: "title 5" },
    ], title: "title 4" },
  ], title: "title 2" }
}
```

What I need is each time user clicks on the image component, If the product has childs item and the length of it was bigger than 0 redirect the child to the current route and get the children array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it properly, but you may have a recursive route, right?
Nuxt's Unknown Dynamic Nested Routes may help here IMO: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes

If you organize your pages like this

```
pages/
--| people/
-----| _id.vue
-----| index.vue
--| _.vue
--| index.vue
```

You'll get the following routes

```
/ -> index.vue
/people -> people/index.vue
/people/123 -> people/_id.vue
/about -> _.vue
/about/careers -> _.vue
/about/careers/chicago -> _.vue
```

Comment: You are right somehow! but what I don't know is how to handle it, when I click on each Image component returns the child data for me and recreates the page!

Comment: @NiazEstefaie not sure about the actual code, but the idea is to have something recursive when you click on something? On click, you could create the dynamic path like `/image/abc/def/ghi` via your payload, the `_.vue` component should catch it and then, you can look into your nested result and get the data you're looking for manually or with something like https://deepdash.io/ So, don't recreate the page, just fetch the data once you're here.